# Moving images from one album to another

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, photos, gallery

I would like to move images from one album to another. When I select **Move**, my phone displays two albums only ("pictures" and "upload"). The problem is that I'd like to move a picture to "all downloads", which I cannot select.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this the (G+) photos app or Gallery or some manufacturer specific gallery app?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and open [Xplore File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&hl=en). (This can be done with any file manager, but Xplore is easy to use.)
2. Navigate to the folder **to which you want to move the pictures**.
3. Swipe left, and you will see a list of folders on your right. Select the images you want to move by **tapping the ticks on their sides**.
4. **Long**-press on one of the files, and select **Move** from the menu that pops up. Then press **okay**.

Answer (score 0):

First long click on the image you want, select options came and again long click on the image then drag and drop the image to any album you want.

Comment: when I select 'move' in settings, it only gives me two possible albums to select from, neither is the one I want to move the image to.  The other albums aren't visible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a file browser like androzip or es file manager and locate them in the folders move them that way (Camera photos are in DCIM others will be in downloads) usually a long press and move should do it